# How to apply a function to every pixel in an xarray dataset?

Tags: dataset, dask, python-xarray

I have an xarray dataset composed of several raster layers that represent stacked, aligned properties of forests. I want to apply a decision tree to this xarray dataset to come up with classes that combine the various forest properties. I want to parallelize this with dask because the decision tree will be applied over a very large area multiple times with over 15 input layers and dozens of end nodes. I think this is similar to the unresolved question [here](https://stackoverflow.com) in that we both want to apply some custom function to every pixel, although here I specifically want something that will work with dask chunks.

Here's a sample xarray dataset:

```
import xarray as xr

peat = [[1, 1], [0, 0]] 
fire_recent = [[1, 0], [1, 0]] 
lon = [[-99.83, -99.32], [-99.79, -99.23]]
lat = [[42.25, 42.21], [42.63, 42.59]]

ds_2x2 = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        peat=(["x", "y"], peat),
        fire_recent=(["x", "y"], fire_recent),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        lon=(["x", "y"], lon),
        lat=(["x", "y"], lat),
    ),
)
```

And here's a sample decision tree I want to apply. Note that the actual decision tree is much more complex.

```
class LossInPeat():
  def __init__(self, no_peat, peat):
    self.no_peat = no_peat
    self.peat = peat
  
  def classify(self, ds_2x2):
    if ds_2x2.peat == 0:
      return 'NoPeat'
    else:
      return 'Peat'
```

Then I try to apply my decision tree with the following

```
loss_in_peat = LossInPeat(
      no_peat=None,
      peat=None
)

loss_in_peat.classify(ds_2x2)
```

I get the error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` I understand from other posts about this error that it is occurring because it's trying to evaluate the entire array using if statement, not an individual pixel. How do I make xarray apply the decision tree to each pixel of stacked layers in a way that can then be run with chunks using dask?

I've tried `apply_ufunc` (e.g.,

```
def decision_tree(a):
    func = lambda x: loss_in_peat.classify(a)
    return xr.apply_ufunc(func, a))
```

but get the same error about using `a.any()` or `a.all()` I mentioned above. Thanks very much.